# how to fix values of x axis in R hist graph

Tags: r

I use the below code to draw a hist graph, but the x axis shows 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, I wish to remove "1.5, 2.5, 3.5", I just wish to see values (1,2,3,4) on x axis, may I know how to do it?

```
h<-hist(nulan$data, breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4), col="red",xlim = c(1,4), xlab="data",main="")
```

below is the graph:[image]

Comment: Have a look at `?axis`, and in particular the `at` parameter.

Comment: So in your case, you would add `xaxt="n"` to your `hist` call, and then `axis(1, at=1:4)`.